# Threaded BaseHTTPServer, one thread per request

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to create an multi-threaded web server using `BaseHttpServer` and `ThreadingMixIn` (as seen on various examples). Pseudo code would be something like:

```
class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
             pass
    def do_POST(self):
             pass

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 9999), Handler)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

This works as expected, but my problem is that not every request gets a thread, but threading is done per URL. I've tested it like this: I have an URL bound to execute the following method:

```
import time
import datetime

def request_with_pause(self):
    print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), 'REQUEST RECEIVED'
    time.sleep(10)
    print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"), 'SENT RESPONSE'
```

It works fine, except when I call the url **twice with a 5 second pause** (click the URL, wait 5 seconds and click it another time) - both "responses" arrive after 10 seconds (response of first click).

Comment: It seems that this code is incomplete I have tried write own `do_GET` with `sleep` and It is working correctly

Comment: could you post your `do_GET` for me to see it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/oleg-chubin/7115594#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: Thank you for your help. Turns out my server was working as expected, but the client side is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2.7:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from threading import Thread

class ThreadedHTTPServer(HTTPServer):
    def process_request(self, request, client_address):
        thread = Thread(target=self.__new_request, args=(self.RequestHandlerClass, request, client_address, self))
        thread.start()
    def __new_request(self, handlerClass, request, address, server):
        handlerClass(request, address, server)
        self.shutdown_request(request)

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("hello world")

server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 80), Handler)
#server.serve_forever()
```

You can find the main source code of the *HTTPServer* class in **SocketServer.py** which you can find in the **Lib** folder in the Python directory. (*HTTPServer* is inherited from *TCPServer*, *TCPServer* is inherited from *BaseServer*.)

The important line is 315:

```
def process_request(self, request, client_address):
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
    self.shutdown_request(request)

def finish_request(self, request, client_address):
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
```

In this point the server create new request object with your Handler class. The *BaseRequestHandler* constructor automatically call the self.setup(), self.handle() and the self.finish() method.

So what I did was to override the process_request method to move this stuff in a new thread.